# Auto generate link for newly registered user

Tags: java, web-services, email-verification

I want to make auto generated link for newly created

user that mywebapp will send to the user's email. When

the user clicks the link i should update the user as

'activated'.

So I've got some questions and I want to understand if

from  what I've read so far my logic is right.

1. user fills in a form and press enter

2.My web service process the data and create an account......

So is here the part where i hash the typed password with some unique salt and store it in the database.

so i will have a table like

```
user_ID   username         password                 active 

1           taniamm20     12346645556665566666       0
```

can i use this hashed password in the verification link for example

```
http://localhost:9092/localbusscat/services/localbusscat/UpdateDB?choID=12346645556665566666
```

Is it a good practice ?

Or at this point i should not save the password of the user and just save user_id and generate long unique key using java.UUIID for that user and save it in the table and use this unique key for verification.

I think my UpdateDBService should look likethis

```
public  String  UpdateDB(int choID ) throws ClassNotFoundException 
        {

            String strDelReturn = "UPDATE_FAIL";

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            try 
            {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("....");
            }

            catch (SQLException ex) 
            {

                ex.printStackTrace();
            }


            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            String selectQuery = "update user_table set active=active+1 WHERE password="+ choID ;

            try {

                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(selectQuery);
                int rowss = pstmt.executeUpdate();
                if (rowss != 0) 
                    strDelReturn = "UPDATE_OK";

            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {

            }
            return strDelReturn;
}
```

Comment: I think, that you should create a random, alphanumeric string and store it in a 'temporary database', along with a validation timeout etc. If the link isn't clicked after 'x' minutes, the validation expires and the link becomes invalid. Of course, said string must be unique in the database. After validation, update your 'active flag' (or do a 'first insert' into your actual user database) and you're all set.

Comment: If the hashed password is used for login, you should maybe generate another hash and use that as the activation code.

Comment: In addition to refugnic-eternium comment you can use date in long format as unique ID so it will be easy to calculate which link is expired link. But while generating date in long keep method synchronized :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion makes use of a second table, called `pending`.

It's basically an 'extension' of the users table, or a copy of the main data, depending on your structure.

This table, in it's purest form, would look like this:

```
UID (int), ActCode (Varchar[x]), ValidUntil (int)
```

UID and ActCode are both unique, meaning that only one ActCode may be issued per UID at a time, and each ActCode can only be associated once. ValidUntil contains the return value of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + x seconds`...whatever you want your validity period to be.

This structure suggests, that the actual user table has `id, userdata, activated` as columns.

If the link isn't used for x seconds, the link becomes invalid (`UNIX_TIMESTAMP() > ValidUntil`) and a new activation link may be generated, while the old one gets deleted.

Alternatively, you can fetch (with each activation related request) the overdue activations and remove the userdata associated with it.

If the link is clicked within the interval, you would remove the activation code and update your user flag.

Another option would be the extended user table:

```
ActCode, ValidUntil, Userdata
```

This way, your UserTable is kept out of the selects entirely, you would insert `UserData` only if the ActCode is used while it's still valid.
This protects your AutoIncrement from non-activated accounts and you don't need a `Activated` field in your user table either...because as soon as it's in your user table, it's activated.

Answer (score 1):

Activation is separate from authentication, it is generally used to make sure the user enters a valid email address that they have access to (or any contact details).

You should generate a separate unique code to activate a user and email the link with that code rather than the password.

Now I may be wrong here but you seem to be under the impression that hashing the password makes it ok to transfer it via emails. It's not, at the best case scenario you are giving an attacker something to brute-force.

After activation ask the user to log in with their credentials.